# Variable is not defined in object

Tags: javascript, object, timer

I have declared an object with variables and methods.
Here it is simplified

```
var myObj = {
    myTimer: null,
    startTimer: function(){
        clearTimeout(myObj.myTimer);
        myObj.myTimer = setTimeout("myObj.myFunction()", 250);
    },
    myFunction: function(){
        alert('Hi');
    }
};
```

After startTimer is invoked, the following errors is printed to the console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: startTimer is not defined
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: works for me, at least in Chrome

Comment: Works for me too! Did you try `myObj.startTimer()` ?

Comment: Hmm that's weird, my code follows the exact same structure but with more specific variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually nothing wrong with my code, although it could probably be more pretty.

The problem was how i was calling the methods, and not within the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass function to `setTimeout` instead of string and it is better to use `this` instead of object name:

```
var myObj = {
    myTimer: null,
    startTimer: function(){
        clearTimeout(this.myTimer);
        this.myTimer = setTimeout(this.myFunction, 2500);
    },
    myFunction: function(){
        alert('Hi');
    }
};
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/fpZBa/